# В мобильной версии при открытии меню слева иногда бывает, что загружается профиль на StackExchange

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия

На верхней панели слева есть кнопка-гамбургер. Она должна открывать меню, но иногда вместо этого загружает профиль на StackExchange.

Android, Chrome

Comment: В десктопной тоже самое, если нажать на гамбургер до того как страница полностью загрузится

Comment: Мобильная версия скоро будет не нужна.

Comment: @alexolut, почему!???

Comment: Вот [поэтому](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311366/what-is-the-responsiveness).

Comment: @alexolut, ну и где плюс? Контент страниц все равно нужен урезанный для мобилок. Мне вот с этой _"фичей"_ что, зумить всегда надо будет?

Comment: Зачем зумить? Responsive дизайн подразумевает перенос контента в зависимости от ширины экрана. Попробуйте сами пока на MSE. Должно быть понятно.

Comment: @alexolut, так я пробую... В десктопной версии список вопросов задизайнен под десктопы, а в мобильной - меньше инфы, сжато для мобилок. Зачем мне эта фича то если она берет и сжимает десктопную версию под размер мобилки?

Comment: Фича в том, что не нужно поддерживать две версии сайта (десктоп и мобильная).

Comment: @alexolut, то есть вы считаете, что подгон контента под экран лучше чем мобильная версия? Я вот пробую с этой фичей лазить, кругом вижу панели и справа и слева, которые вроде на десктопе не мешают, а на мобилке - ой как бесят

Comment: Я не оцениваю фичу, как лучше/хуже. Я лишь говорю, что мобильную версию сайта этой фичей планируют искоренить.

Comment: @alexolut, где им можно минус поставить?)

Comment: Например, [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/339911), но это ничего не изменит. Тут нет демократии :)

Comment: Хм, текст вопроса и комменты под ним в этом вашем responsive слегка удавлены. Но если это пофиксить, то в целом мне нравится, никаких "панелей и справа и слева" вообще-то нету (однако не оффтопите ли вы тут?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты успеваешь нажать на неё до того, как страница загрузится полностью. В этом случае на неё ещё нет обработки клика и она срабатывает как обычная ссылка (как это было бы при отключенном js) и отправляет на страницу с аналогичной информацией.

Comment: Но ведь. Эт ж баг

Comment: @Flippy [tag:bug-design]

Comment: @Suvitruf, о! Точно