# Кривая работа кнопки «Последние входящие сообщения»

Tags: дефект

Когда заходишь на ruSO ты видишь кол-во входящих сообщений, если оно не нулевое, кликаешь по соответствующей кнопке. Но если при входе на сайт это сделать быстро, то тебе откроется страница регистрации на metaSE. Такая же канитель с кнопками «Последние достижения», «Список всех сайтов SE», «Очередь проверок» (не выпадающее окно, а сразу все очереди проверок). Возможно, это не все кнопки.

По-моему это ошибка, и её, как и любую другую (за редким исключением) ошибку, нужно исправить.

EDIT: Этот баг был обнаружен в PC версии.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Картинок бы поясняющих.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В мобильной версии при открытии меню слева иногда бывает, что загружается профиль на StackExchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7743/%d0%92-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb)

Comment: Кажется, если после обновления страницы также быстро нажать на кнопку очереди проверок, то попадаешь на страницу всех очередей, а должен быть выпадающий список.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в поиск браузера введи URL ruSO. Когда прогрузилась кнопка нажми на нёё (надо делать быстро). Тебе высветятся не последние сообщения, а страница регистрации на metaSE

Comment: @nomnoms12 -1. Там о мобильной версии – тут об компьютерной версии

Comment: Гифку бы добавить

Comment: @αλεχολυτ 1. Всё понятно. 2. Каких скринов? Промотай страницу кверху и посмотри)

Comment: @return Вопрос, который я привёл выше, действительно о мобильной версии. Но баг тот же — не успевают загрузиться скрипты, и при нажатии происходит переход на metaSE.

Comment: @Qwertiy раз уж всё понятно, то мог бы и дубликатом закрыть, учитывая одинаковые ответы к тому же.

Comment: Угу, у меня тоже так иногда.

Answer (score 2):

Все обработчики вешаются когда страница полностью загрузилась. Если ты успеваешь нажать раньше, то срабатывает ссылка - как если бы сайт был открыт с отключенными скриптами.

Теоретически улучшить можно, но я сильно сомневаюсь, что кто-то этим будет заниматься.